# How to use a parameter derived from a Table, given I'm filtering the table in query

Tags: mysql, subquery

The task is to find what fraction of total users have logged in at least for one more consecutive day after their first login.

````
SELECT 
    ROUND( COUNT( b.player_id )/COUNT( DISTINCT (SELECT a.player_id FROM Activity a) ), 2 ) AS fraction
FROM 
    Activity b
WHERE 
    (b.player_id, DATE_ADD(b.event_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) IN
(
    SELECT 
        player_id, MIN(event_date)
    FROM 
        Activity
    GROUP BY 
        player_id
)```
````

The table structure is as follows

Table: Activity

```
+--------------+---------+
| Column Name  | Type    |
+--------------+---------+
| player_id    | int     |
| device_id    | int     |
| event_date   | date    |
| games_played | int     |
+--------------+---------+

Activity table:
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| player_id | device_id | event_date | games_played |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| 1         | 2         | 2016-03-01 | 5            |
| 1         | 2         | 2016-03-02 | 6            |
| 2         | 3         | 2017-06-25 | 1            |
| 3         | 1         | 2016-03-02 | 0            |
| 3         | 4         | 2018-07-03 | 5            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

I'm using two aliases a and b for the same table for referring them.

- a is for the unfiltered table, because I need a count of all Distinct users.
- b is for the filtered table, where only those rows are included for which a condition is met.

Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Some example input data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  This sounds like a good use case for a CTE that finds the `player_id, MIN(event_date)`.

Comment: @J.D. @Rick James The version is MySQL 8.0. I found out the error. I wrote  ```COUNT( DISTINCT (SELECT a.player_id FROM Activity a) )```,  which doesn't make sense. It should be ```SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.player_id FROM Activity a)```